# Randomized function with a communication size restriction

Tags: randomized-algorithms, pseudo-random-generators

I need to create a randomized function between two participants, 1 and 2. The two participants have both n bit sized strings, and they want to determine whatever they have the same strings.
1 and 2 can communicate using only log(n) bits. The probability of error should be at most 1/3, but the function can be run multiple time and take a "majority vote" for which conclusion appeared in most of the runs, in order to decrease the error probability.

I have tried multiple ideas - for example, using a hash function where the "random" part in the algorithm is that 1 chose a random hash method each run and communicate it to 2 using the log(n) bits. But it's either that I can't prove that the probability of error is at most 1/3 or that I need to use more then log(n) bits, do you have an idea how to achieve it ?

Comment: View the strings that the participants have as non-negative integers between $0$ and $2^n-1$. Have participant $1$ choose a random prime number $p$ from the interval $[n,2n]$ and reduce his string/integer modulo $p$. Have him then send participant $2$ the choice of $p$ and the residue mod $p$ (which takes around $2\log n$ bits). Have participant $2$ declare that he and participant $1$ have the same string if and only if participant $2$'s string/integer has the same residue mod $p$ as participant $1$'s string/integer. The observation is that if participant $1$ and $2$'s strings differ, then

Comment: with high probability, participant $2$ will declare so.